# Mobile menu disappears when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with [my website](https://estoas.dk) when i open the menu on a mobile or tablet, it opens just fine, but when i want to scroll, the menu disappears immediately.

Can you help me make the menu opened until the customer close it?

Comment: I've looked in the global.css file, but cant seem to find the element, the shop is created with Prestashop, but it's obvious just a CSS file that controlls the menu.

Answer (score 0):

For the styling file (mobile version) you should do the following:

```
topnav{position: absolute;}
```

Comment: But the problem is also, as i wrote in a comment, i cant find the element for the mobile part, i've tried in the css file, there is a part called title-menu-mobile and menu-content, i've tried to edit both, so the position is absolute, but it dont make any difference.